# What is the difference between forM and forM_ in haskell?

Tags: haskell

HLint suggests that I use `forM_` rather than `forM`. Why? I see they have different type signatures but haven't found a good reason to use one over the other.

```
forM  :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t a -> (a -> m b) -> m (t b)
forM_ :: (Foldable t,    Monad m) => t a -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
```

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the naming conventions in Control.Monad (where forM and forM_ come from): http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Control-Monad.html#g:3

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `forM_` function is more efficient because it does not save the results of the operations.  That is all.  (This only makes sense when working with monads because a pure function of type `a -> ()` is not particularly useful.)

Comment: However, because of laziness, the list returned by forM is never computed unless used . In other words, whenever one does not need the resulting list, forM could be used in place of forM_ with no loss of efficiency. But forM_ is preferred becasue it has a more informative type in this case.

Comment: @Federico That's not exactly true.  Even if the elements of the list are not computed there is still overhead in creating the spine of the list.  There is also a space leak during the `forM` call because it holds on to the list elements.

Comment: Also, it's *semantically* nicer to use `forM_`; it tells the reader that the effects are the only important part of this monadic action.

Comment: `rnf :: NFData => a -> ()`. Its useful for more than monads ;)

Comment: Yeah, but isn't that a special form (or at least uses one behind its definition)?

Comment: @monadic: Not completely useless, but `rnf` can be replaced with `const ()` with no semantic changes in any program that doesn't do bizarre tricks with `IO`.

Comment: @trinithis No, it is simply a typeclass function. `deepseq` basically forces the `()` to be evaluated.

Comment: The issue of `forM` vs `forM_` and the relative (in)efficiency was just brought up on a [-cafe thread](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2017-September/127885.html).  The short of it is that a `forM` version of initializing a Vector took 40ms while `forM_`, thanks to not building and tossing the extra structure, took just under a millisecond.

Answer (score 12):

Ok,

```
forM is mapM with its arguments flipped.

forM_ is mapM_ with its arguments flipped.
```

Let's see in mapM and mapM_ :

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

`mapM mf xs` takes a monadic function `mf` (having type `Monad m => (a -> m b)`) and applies it to each element in list `xs`; the result is a list inside a monad. 
The difference between `mapM` and `mapM_` is, that `mapM` returns a list of the results, while `mapM_` returns an empty result. The result of each action in `mapM_` is not stored.

Answer (score 7):

To understand the difference between **(A)**: `forM xs f` and **(B)**: `forM_ xs f`, it might help to compare the difference between the following:

```hs
-- Equivalent to (A)
do
  r1 <- f x1
  r2 <- f x2
  ...
  rn <- f xn
  return [r1, r2, ..., rn]

-- Equivalent to (B)
do
  _ <- f x1
  _ <- f x2
  ...
  _ <- f xn
  return ()
```

The crucial difference being that `forM_` ignores the results `r1`, ... `rn` and just returns an empty result via `return ()`. Think of the underscore as meaning "don't care" ... `forM_` *doesn't care* about the results. `forM` however, *does* care about the results and returns them in as a list via `return [r1, r2, ... rn]`.

---

**Example 1**
The code below asks for your name three times and prints the results of the forM.

```hs
import Control.Monad (forM, forM_)

main = do
  let askName i = do
      putStrLn $ "What's your name (" ++ (show i) ++ ")"
      name <- getLine
      return name
  results <- forM [1,2,3] askName
  putStrLn $ "Results = " ++ show results
```

An example execution with `forM`:

```
What's your name? (1)
> James
What's your name? (2)
> Susan
What's your name? (3)
> Alex
Results = ["James", "Susan", "Alex"]
```

But if we change the `forM` to a `forM_`, then we would have instead:

```
What's your name? (1)
> James
What's your name? (2)
> Susan
What's your name? (3)
> Alex
Results = ()
```

---

In your case, the linter is telling you that you're not using the return values of your `forM` (you don't have `foo <- forM xs f`, you probably have `forM xs f` by itself on a line) and so should use `forM_` instead. This happens, for 
example, when you are using a monadic action like `putStrLn`.

---

**Example 2** The code below asks for your name and then says "Hello" – repeating three times.

```
import Control.Monad (forM, forM_)

main = do
  let askThenGreet i = do
      putStrLn $ "What's your name (" ++ (show i) ++ ")"
      name <- getLine
      putStrLn $ "Hello! " ++ name
  forM [1,2,3] askThenGreet
```

An example execution with `forM`:

```
 What's your name? (1)
> Sarah
Hello! Sarah

What's your name? (2)
> Dick
Hello! Dick

What's your name? (3)
> Peter
Hello! Peter

[(), (), ()]
```

The overall result of `main` comes from the result of the forM: `[(), (), ()]`. It's pretty useless and annoyingly, it appears in the console. But if we change the `forM` to a `forM_`, then we would have instead:

```
What's your name? (1)
> Sarah
Hello! Sarah

What's your name? (2)
> Dick
Hello! Dick

What's your name? (3)
> Peter
Hello! Peter
```

With that change, the overall result comes from the `mapM_` and is now `()`. This doesn't show up in the console (a quirk of the IO monad)! Great! 
Also, by using `mapM_` here, it's clearer to other readers of your code – you're indirectly explaining / self-documenting that you *don't care* about the results `[r1, ..., rn] = [(), (), ()]` – and rightly so as they're useless here.